# Latex removing "Listing #"

Tags: listings

I am working on a C++ reference manual for myself and want good looking listing code blocks.

This stack overflow question was very helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741985/latex-source-code-listing-like-in-professional-books

But for the life of me I can't find anywhere on the internet for information regarding how to remove the "Listing #" part of the listing captions.

Below is a screenshot of what I have:

[image]

I want to remove the front part of the listing caption but still have a caption because i want to say the filename.

Answer (score 5):

There is also the `title` option, it is like `caption` with no number or prefix.

Answer (score 4):

I can't answer it fully but the command you are looking for should be `\captionsetup`.

E.g.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption = A sample caption]
public void helloWorld(){...
\end{lstlistning}

\end{document}
```

This causes the caption (every caption, listing or not) not to have Listing # (or Figure #, for that matter).

You might want to look into the doc here http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/caption/ to adapt it to you needs. Please post a solution